# How to AND all BIT column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a BIT column in a SQL Server table and I want to calculate AND of all of them. I tried this:

```
DECLARE @AreON BIT = 1  
    SELECT @AreON = @OUT_AreON & [dbo].[fnIsEnabled](VALUE) FROM [dbo].SplitByComma(@IN_IDs)

    IF (@AreON = 1) BEGIN
        SET @OUT_AreON = 1
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SET @OUT_AreON = 0
    END
```

`[dbo].[fnIsEnabled]` is a function that returns BIT. While `[dbo].[fnIsEnabled]` is returning 1 for all of the seperate inputs, @AreON is 0 at the end of execution. Is `&` the correct way to AND two BIT columns or I am wrong doing this?

Comment: What value has `@OUT_AreON` at the beginning?

Comment: It is an out parameter of a procedure and has no value before these lines

Comment: OUT_AreON is being set explicitly and conditionally based on result of AreON after select being called.

Comment: `@OUT_AreON & [dbo].[fnIsEnabled](VALUE)` think about it

Comment: since @OUT_AreON is null I've declare a temporary variable AreON, assigned it 1 so that if other values AND with it, its value indicate the result of anding all of them

Comment: `SELECT @OUT_AreON = MIN(CONVERT(INT, dbo.fnIsEnabled(VALUE))) FROM [dbo].SplitByComma(@IN_IDs)` is a (less intuitive) alternative.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Meanwhile beautiful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
SELECT @AreON = @OUT_AreON & [dbo].[fnIsEnabled](VALUE) ...
```

with

```
SELECT @AreON = @AreON & [dbo].[fnIsEnabled](VALUE) ...
```